# Select only URLs separated by commas with REGEX

Tags: json, regex

My objective is to put all the URLs between `""` so I'm trying to select them without the comma `,` then I will use the regular expression to do a large search/replace.

My current REGEX: `"BigImage":\s(\[(.*)\])`

I tried this but it doesn't work: `"BigImage":\s(\[([^,]+)\])`

```
"BigImage": [http://example.com/1.jpg,http://example.com/2.jpg,http://example.com/3.jpg]
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/nE5eV3/30

Comment: where do you get your data from? Is the structure everytime the same? if yes, you dont need regex: substring to first [ and then remove last ] then use split(',') to get alle the urls

Comment: It needs to be a regular expression as I'm editing hundreds of files through search / replace in Atom.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a regex for your urls, i don know, if it allways looks the same. For your links the regex would lookls like this:

```
(https?://(www)?[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/[^\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))
```

This regex will match all of your urls (you posted in your question).

**Full Blocks:**

```
("BigImage": \[([^,\]]*,?)*\])
```

If you want to filter the string you posted above, you can use the regex above.

**Tested with [this](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/) site!**

If you post a more complete example of your data, we can help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in fact I only need to find / replace URLS used as values for the key "BigImage". I upated my example here : https://regex101.com/r/nE5eV3/34. All those urls should be contained between "". Is it clearer?